# Range seekbar set range

Tags: java, android

I am using this library for two sided range seek bar *https://github.com/yahoo/android-range-seek-bar*. But when I try to set the min and max values to 0 and 50 crores. It does not work in the manner the ranges are increase and decrease but not the right way i want. Here is [my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OX8qY.png) and [here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieIK9.png) that i want.

xml:

```
    <com.example.asad.homebuyerproject.RangeSeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/rangeSeekBar"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                            android:background="#FFFFFF"
                            android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Activity:

```
public void setvaluerange(View layout) {


    RangeSeekBar r= (RangeSeekBar)layout.findViewById(R.id.rangeSeekBar);

    r.setRangeValues(0,50);
    mseekvaluemax=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekValuemax);
    mseekvaluemin=(TextView)layout.findViewById(R.id.seekValuemin);


    r.setOnRangeSeekBarChangeListener(new RangeSeekBar.OnRangeSeekBarChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onRangeSeekBarValuesChanged(RangeSeekBar bar, Object minValue, Object maxValue) {

            mseekvaluemin.setText( minValue.toString());
            mseekvaluemax.setText(maxValue.toString());
            bar.getAbsoluteMaxValue();
            bar.getAbsoluteMinValue();

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Max" + bar.getAbsoluteMaxValue().toString() +"Min"+  bar.getAbsoluteMinValue().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            //  r.resetSelectedValues();


        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the units of the range values like so:

```
mseekvaluemin.setText( minValue.toString() + " Lacs");
mseekvaluemax.setText(maxValue.toString() + " Crores");
```

That will show the units for you.

Comment: but when value goes down from 50 crores to lacs how to display?

Comment: You will have to write the logic for that in the onRangeSeekBarValuesChange method. I am not sure when the change would take place. But you would have to check the maxValue and see if it has changed to the other unit (lacs).